# How to hide a container when all entries are filtered in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I use a filter in my AngularJS 1.4.3 application. 
What I will do is that if **vm.nightServices** is filtered an no entry is shown (so all are filtered) than the div container should be hidden. I have tried **ng-show="vm.nightServices.length > 0"** but it does not work.

```
<div ng-show="vm.nightServices.length > 0" ng-repeat="nightService in vm.nightServices | filter:institutionOfUserFilter.institutionName">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new filtered list in your ng-repeat for which you can check the length in your ng-show.

```
<div ng-repeat="nightService in filtered = ( vm.nightServices | filter:institutionOfUserFilter.institutionName )" ng-show="filtered.length > 0">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide a parent DOM element, filter your list in your controller using $filter. Store the result in the scope and use that result.

Note : if you do this you will have to add a $scope.$watch on the list to update the filtered one if this list can change.